# Getting instances of user-defined classes

Tags: c++, class

I'm a beginner with C++ and now have a problem with one of my classes. I have a vector list of my `Sprite` class and I want to get one of items in the list and give it to a method parameter of another class but it just tell me the `Subscript range is out of vector`. I examined the list to see is it really containing any item and it was right, the list working great.

My list:

`vector<Core::Graphic::cSprite> Sprites;`

My method:

```
Core::Logic::cGameObject::cGameObject(std::string Name, Core::Graphic::cSprite* Sprite, float X, float Y, int Depth)
{ 
    // Set fields
    this->Name = Name;
    this->Sprite = *Sprite;
    // Add to active sprites
    for(int i = 0; i < this->Sprite.Images.size(); i++)
    {
        // Create temporaroy sprite
        sf::Sprite tempSprite;
        tempSprite.SetImage(this->Sprite.Images[i]);
        this->ActiveSprite.push_back(tempSprite);
    }
    this->X = X;
    this->Y = Y;
    this->Depth = Depth;
    this->ImageIndex = 0;
    this->ImageNumber = this->Sprite.SubFrames;
}
```

My sprite constructor:

```
Core::Graphic::cSprite::cSprite(std::string Name, vector<std::string> ImagesFileNames)
{
    // Check input
    if(Name != "" && ImagesFileNames.max_size() > 0)
    {
        this->Name = Name;
        for(int i = 0; i < ImagesFileNames.size(); i++)
        {
            sf::Image tempImage;
            if(tempImage.LoadFromFile(ImagesFileNames[i])){
              this->Images.push_back(tempImage);
            }
        }
        this->SubFrames = this->Images.max_size();
    }
}
```

I have a `cGameObjectManaher` class to manage game objects and it has a method like below:

```
Game.GameObjectManager.AddGameObject("obj_intro_1", &Game.SpriteManager.Sprites[0], 0, 0, 0);
```

I checked everything in my codes but nothing exceeds out of the lists. I think it's the problem of the code that I implemented.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you have initialized `Game.SpriteManager.Sprites` before using it?

Comment: Exactly the line that I use `Game.GameObjectManager.AddGameObject`. I even commented the whole body of my game object class constructor to see what's wrong but it just keep giving error.

Comment: Yes, I didn't write them here. Everything is right but this list is a real problem!

Comment: The error you getting indicates that size of your vector is smaller or equal than the index of element (in your case 0) you trying to access to. This means that your vector have 0 elements. Please recheck if you initializing its elements correctly, i.e using the interface of the vector class (most probably push_back).

Comment: In the latter code, I'm not sure you really want to be using max_size(), I don't think it's doing what you think it is (look it up). My guess is that you're using Subframes (or a loop to Subframes) as an index somewhere outside of the code you're showing, and it's that that blows up.

Comment: Thank you all, You're right the `max_size()` in my another code is making problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is using `max_size()` which returns the system maximum of items you could theoretically add to the vector instead of `size()` which returns the actual size of the vector. The code you're showing is probably not the code crashing, but instead some code depending on this->Subframes that is set to a HUGE number in your latter code snippet.

As an example, on my machine;

```
std::vector<int> a;
std::cout << a.max_size() << std::endl;
```

returns `4611686018427387903` instead of `0` which you're probably expecting.

Comment: Thanks for answer. You're right I solved it a minute ago, I was thinking that the max_size() would return the max count of items in vector.